# Delete an object in Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This question might not even be related to angularjs and the solution could be plain old js or jquery. But that is what i what to find out.

I want to implement a delete functionality for a particular user and i am wondering if there is a easier way to do this in angularjs or should it be plain old JS?

i have a fairly complex object for eg (going up to 4 levels):

```
{
  "Department": [
    {
      "Name": "Accounting",
      "users": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "firstName": "John",
          "lastName": "Doe",
          "age": 23
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "firstName": "Mary",
          "lastName": "Smith",
          "age": 32
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "Sales",
      "users": [
        {
          "id": "3",
          "firstName": "Sally",
          "lastName": "Green",
          "age": 27
        },
        {
          "id": "4",
          "firstName": "Jim",
          "lastName": "Galley",
          "age": 41
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

this is displayed in a ng-repeat where we should Department and username. If I want to delete a particular user i make an api call and on success of it, I want to delete that object.  so i have a js method like this

```
function DeleteUser(user) {
    $.each(ctrl.UserData, function(index, value) {
        var filteredPeople = value.filter((item) => item.id !== user.id);
    });
```

**The question I have is**, if i want to delete this object is there any easier way to delete from model since i have the object here or i have to do the classic jquery way of using like $.grep or filter to iterate through each object and match by id and then delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you're iterating over the departments (accounting, sales) in your template, and then over the users in that department.

So you could have, in your template:

```
<button ng-click="deleteUser(user, department)">...</button>
```

And the method could thus be as simple as

```
$scope.deleteUser = function(user, department) {
  // delete user from backend, then
  department.users.splice(departments.users.indexOf(user), 1);
}
```

If you really don't want to pass the department, then loop over the departments, and use the above if `departments.users.indexOf(user)` returns a value that is `>= 0`.

Comment: Awesome.. thanks @jb-nizet. yes i am actually passing department. thanks a lot.